# Microk8s Airgap Deployment

Tags: microk8s

- Setting up Microk8s on an offline airgap environment

I saw the offline guide by downloading the microk8s snap however for the addons like kubeflow, metallb,promethus, linkerd, istio are they able to be enabled on the offline environment? Are offline ways to get them installed?